# Strange Notation in Linear Algebra Question

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

I've taken courses on linear algebra before, so I know enough where I can usually get by, but I saw the following question on my homework, and have no idea how to interpret it:

> For the next two questions, let:
>
> $$ B_2 = \Biggl\{ \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\1 & 3\end{bmatrix},
> \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\3 & 1\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}1 & 3\\1 &
> 1\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}3 & 1\\1 & 1\end{bmatrix} \Biggl\} $$
>   $$ B_3 = \Biggl\{ \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix},
> \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\1 &
> 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \Biggl\} $$
>
> Find: $P_{B_3 \leftarrow B_2}$

I have done multiple searches (although I honestly have no idea what to search for at this point) trying to figure out what on Earth "$P_{B_3 \leftarrow B_2}$" could possibly mean in this context, and I have come up with nothing. It looks like it may be referring to polynomial space with "$P$", but that doesn't make any sense given the provided matrices.

Does anyone know what "$P_{B_3 \leftarrow B_2}$" means?

Comment: If this is in the homework, then the notation must be used in class. If you haven’t seen that notation before, you perhaps are not paying enough attention, because you’ve taken linear algebra courses before? Notation varies a lot. You should know what notation is being used in your class. (The other possibility is that your professor is being really, really careless with their assignments)

Comment: @Arturo Magidin if you must know, the professor does have a bit of a reputation here for skipping over critical information. On the other hand, he does offer weekly office hours, so I may start attending those.

Comment: On a side note, Google really needs to allow for searching by MathJax. I couldn't get any results for that notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means "the transition matrix from the (ordered) basis $B_2$ to the (ordered) basis $B_3$". Thus, for this question, it is
$$P_{B_3\leftarrow B_2}=\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1&3\\
1&1&3&1\\
1&3&1&1\\
3&1&1&1\end{bmatrix}$$
It takes a vector in $M_{2×2}(\mathbb R)$ expressed in the basis $B_2$ and returns that same vector in the basis $B_3$.

Comment: Thank you very much!